# Why won't my screws for an electrical box secure to my aluminum siding?

Tags: electrical, screws, mounting

I'm putting a new weatherproof single-gang electrical box on my garage (40 years old), which has some kind of cork frame backing. When I screwed it in it just kept on turning, even when I increased the screw size. The screws aren't catching (like when screwed into stucco). There was an old box on there that had a 12- and 14-gauge illegal connection.  That box was also loose.

Would you recommend a particular anchor for this, or should I just drill a 1-1/2" hole and put a machine screw with a nut on the inside of the garage? (not sure if that is to code). Also, because the electrical box won't lay flat due to the two brackets that protrude out (thus making it impossible to be mounted flush), should I add two more brackets (four in all) so that it would be somewhat flush against the siding? I don't want to put a wall mount behind it. Appreciate your help.

[image: replacing old wall electrical box]

[image: old box]

By the way inside the garage it is like a silver paper backing. The material looks like this - similar to a plaster with a white substance and silver backing[image]

Answer (score 4):

You need longer screws that will bite into the base siding or find a stud. Aluminum sideing is very thin and will not hold well even with larger screws. Since this is a garrage and you mention silver paper backing if that is the only thing behind the sideing you may need to add a nailer between 2 studs to support the box.

Comment: Ed so when you say longer screws into the base does that mean i can run two 2" toggles to hold the electrical box from the back of my frame wall (silver)--is that acceptable according to Nec. Or do as you suggested and add a nailer between 2 studs. Thank u again

Comment: The box needs to be secure if it is with 2" screws that would be fine. If the box moves I would add a nailer. It looks like there is a bushing in the back that will protect the wires from getting cut by the siding if it wiggles. Code dosent define exactly what is required other than it needs to be secured. Looking at the inside photo that may be a insulation layer that probably will not hold so a nailer would be needed.

Comment: Long screws into wood, not toggles into aluminum. Siding is not structural.